# Particular question about "as" preposition

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

I want to know the difference between these 2 sentences.

1. As a mother, I warn you.
2. Like a mother, I warn you.

Comment: The Cambridge Dictionary explains the difference between "as" and "like" (using "father" instead of "mother") https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-or-like

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is spoken by someone who is a mother. It could be rephrased "*I am a mother and I warn you*", They are speaking from the point of view of a mother.

The second sentence is saying "*If I were a mother I would warn you*" the speaker is not necessarily a mother or even female. They are saying what they think a mother would say.

Comment: So the first sentence is like " I'm a mother and therefore i warn you" and second sentence is like "I'm not a mother, but I'm warning you as if i was a mother

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So that "therefore" is correct?

Comment: Yes, you could also say  "_Speaking as a mother, I warn you_". It is speaking from having the of experience of being a mother.

Comment: So 1 means that she's a mother and giving a reason for that obligation, and 2 means that he/she is not mother but indicating that they are warning like a mother, which is emphasizing, right?

Comment: @AnungooGoo The second sentence (unlike the first) doesn't say if the person is a mother or not. So, stop trying to give it a negative meaning (that the person is not a mother). It simply says the person is issuing a warning *in the same way* that mothers do.

Comment: But if she were a mother , why would she tell "like a mother"?